# Mvc: Null values generating error message object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am reading columns from an excel file and assigning to a variable

```
             object sTieToCPI = currentWorkSheet.Cells[rowNumber, 5].Value;
             object sRent = currentWorkSheet.Cells[rowNumber, 7].Value;
             object sWash = currentWorkSheet.Cells[rowNumber, 8].Value;
             object sReplacement = currentWorkSheet.Cells[rowNumber, 9].Value;
             object sSales = currentWorkSheet.Cells[rowNumber, 10].Value;
```

I am doing some validation here before I process the data

```
             if ((sTieToCPI.ToString() == "Y") && ((sRent.ToString() != "") || (sWash.ToString() != "") || (sReplacement.ToString() != "") || (sSales.ToString() != "")))
             {
                validationErr.AppendLine("Invalid Rent/Wash/Sales/Repl values for this Tie-to-CPI: " + sTieToCPI + "  " + "Row:" + rowNumber);
             }
```

Once I get to the above line all I get is "object reference not set to an instance of an object"
 I think this is because sRent,sWash,sReplacement and sSales are null.

Here was my attempt to solve the null problem below

```
             if (sRent.ToString()) == null)
             {
                sRent = "";
             }

             if (sWash.ToString() == null)
             {
                sWash = "";
             }


             if ((sTieToCPI.ToString() == "Y") && ((sRent.ToString() != "") || (sWash.ToString() != "") || (sReplacement.ToString() != "") || (sSales.ToString() != "")))
             {
                validationErr.AppendLine("Invalid Rent/Wash/Sales/Repl values for this Tie-to-CPI: " + sTieToCPI + "  " + "Row:" + rowNumber);
             }
```

My attempt did not solve it but am still getting the error message "object reference not set to an instance of an object"

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't call `ToString` on `null` object.

Try..

```
if (sRent == null)
```

or, even better...

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)sRent))
```

Comment: Remember that this is stored as an object object sRent = currentWorkSheet.Cells[rowNumber, 7].Value; Don't i need to convert this to a string

Comment: When I followed your way, this is what I got. The best overloaded method for string.IsNullOrEmpty(string) has some invalid arguments

Answer (score 0):

You could simply cast the objects to `string`:

```
string sTieToCPI = currentWorkSheet.Cells[rowNumber, 5].Value as string;
```

Note that, if you want a default value (ie, set to an empty string if null), then use the [null-coalescing `??`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx):

```
string sTieToCPI = currentWorkSheet.Cells[rowNumber, 5].Value as string ?? "";
```

But really you just need the cast `as string`, and then the check would be simplified to:

```
if (sTieToCPI == "Y" && 
    (sRent != null || sWash != null || sReplacement != null) || sSales != null)
)
```